# Source variables from a bash script into a Jenkins build

Tags: bash, jenkins, jenkins-plugins

Hi there I am working on a Jenkins plugin for propertiery "standard software" which uses Gradle and is bound to some environment Variables.

The bash script to build such projects looks a bit like this:

```
#!/bin/bash

source <someOtherFile>.sh

cd $VAR_FROM_SOME_OTHER_FILE
for subproject in $VAR_FROM_SOME_OTHER_FILE2
# gradle magic
# ...
# and so on
```

So my question is, since .sh is controlled via git how to source it in a jenkins build step? This could be an extra plugin or a programmatic approach.

I also looked at the [EnvInject plugin](https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/EnvInject+Plugin) but it does not provide that required feature. One can execute the script but the exported variables will be lost after execution.

Comment: How long after execution do you want to have the environment variables available? Define "lost after execution".
Why don't you just run that script by Jenkins, too?

Comment: @StephenKing "How long" - Just for that build(step), Why I don't run it? Well, how to run it :D?

Comment: All exported variables should be available for the whole build AFAIK.

Comment: Regarding "how to run it"? How to run a shell script? Your sheebang is wrong (should be `#!/bin/bash`).

Comment: @StephenKing I corrected the sheebang. I can't just run the script. I want to source it, like source you would source variables in a bash script. If I execute <someOtherFile>.sh in a shell Build Step those variables won't persist to the next build step.

Comment: How are the variables defined? With `export VAR=value`?

Comment: @StephenKing correct